Centering a standalone for a 0.6cm squared paper
Since I cannot find 0.6 cm squared paper I decided to create my own. This is the trivial code I managed to write so far but there are two "problems".
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\sqw{1}
\newcommand\square[4][1]{\fill[#4] (#2*\sqw,#3*\sqw) rectangle +(#1*\sqw,#1*\sqw);}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\sqw{0.6}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=\sqw, gray!37] (0,0) grid (34*\sqw, 47*\sqw);    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


First: the grid is not centered. I know that \begin{center} does not work with standalone. I tried to change the document-class type but nothing worked well.

Second: is there a way to fulfill the whole paper with a squared grid? I mean in order to not having the border of the rectangle?


Thank you so much!

Did you try the gridpapers package?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Well, there is always something to learn... Thank you!

Or the graphpaper package

This version

uses only xcolor and depends on no third-party packages12;
requires only a single compilation;
does not require loading the behemoth tikz3;
uses the flashy new hooks thingies now provided by the kernel;
uses the ancient4 method preferred by some for drawing aeroplanes, donkeys and such things.


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730929/
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcounter{vcount}
\newcounter{hcount}
\newlength{\gridsize}
\setlength{\gridsize}{6mm}
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \setcounter{vcount}{\inteval{\paperwidth/\gridsize}}%
  \addtocounter{vcount}{-1}%
  \setcounter{hcount}{\inteval{\paperheight/\gridsize}}%
  \addtocounter{hcount}{-1}%
}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\unitlength}{6mm}%
  \color{gray!50}%
  \multiput(1,0)(1,0){\value{vcount}}{%
    \line(0,-1){\paperheight}%
  }%
  \multiput(0,-1)(0,-1){\value{hcount}}{%
    \line(1,0){\paperwidth}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\mbox{ }
\end{document}

1I do not know whether this is an advantage or, if it is, whether it is a significant one. On the whole, I am dubious about the advantages of dispensing with third-party packages. (And, of course, they are not really 'third-party' but fourth- or fifth- or sixth-party .... But the claim seems to be popularly regarded as an advantage, so you may make up your own mind.a
2xcolor is one of the vast arrayb of packages maintained by the LaTeX Project or members thereof.
3An excellent, but hefty, packagec.
4Just before contemporary if you're a philosopher. No, they didn't have picture mode in the modern era. Perhaps you're thinking of paintd?
aI'm not sure who else's mind you might try to make up, but such attempts are ethically dubious, imho. Don't you have enough to do making up your own?
barray naturally being another.
cDon't you have better things to do than reading footnotes to footnotes*?
dNot to be confused with Paint**.
*Yes, I have better things to do than writing them or, at least, more constructive ones, but I'm stuck on my main procrastination project so I have to do this instead.
**No, not that either. Think post-Kantian pre-Babbage.

This answer must be accepted because both of its simplicity and, most of all, because of the notes, footnotes, side notes and so on :D It was a pleasure to read.

Also, this is perfect.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzpagenodes}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page)}]
\draw[help lines, step=0.6cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



There is something wrong with this because I don't obtain the full squared page, but only a small portion at the top right...

Weird... I compiled again and it worked. Didn't touch anything...

[remember picture] takes two runs.  It stores the location of the origin in the aux file in order to locate anything else on the page (relative to the origin).

@JohnKormylo I didn't know this, thank you. I am going to make myself a knowledge of this
